# ML.NET OLSTrainer on Macos with an arm M1 processor error with libomp

Tags: macos, .net-core, apple-m1, ml.net

I am trying to use a ml.net's OLSTrainer on a Mac with an M1 processor but I get the error below and was looking for some assistance.

Unhandled exception. System.NotSupportedException: The MKL library (libMklImports) or one of its dependencies is missing.
at Microsoft.ML.Trainers.OlsTrainer.TrainCore(IChannel ch, Factory cursorFactory, Int32 featureCount)

Microsoft documentation points me to this link/version to install, but makes no difference.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/install-extra-dependencies

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/fb8323f2b170bd4ae97e1bac9bf3e2983af3fdb0/Formula/libomp.rb && brew install ./libomp.rb && brew link libomp --force
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the current Timeseries support is dependent on Intel SDKs, and does not support Apple Silicon directly.

https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/main/docs/project-docs/platform-limitations.md